# Apache camel-The type must implement the inherited abstract method error

Tags: compiler-errors, port, apache-camel, abstract

i have been findling around camel for quite a while now.
And I have written this small piece of code that would forward all the incoming request
on port 8080 to two servers vmxp22-sat-1:8080 and vmxp22-sat-1:8080

```
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.camel.AsyncCallback;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.Endpoint;
import org.apache.camel.processor.loadbalancer.LoadBalancer;


public class Test implements LoadBalancer  {

    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                // START SNIPPET: e1
                from("jetty://http://localhost:8080")
                .loadBalance().roundRobin()
                .to("http://vmxp22-sat-1:8080",
                    "http://vmxp22-sat-2:8080");
                // END SNIPPET: e1


            }
        };
    }
}
```

But when i comiple it on eclipse I get the following error

```
The type Test must implement the inherited abstract method AsyncProcessor.process(Exchange, AsyncCallback)  Test.java   /first_camel/src/main/java/com/mycompany/first_camel    line 24 Java Problem
The type Test must implement the inherited abstract method LoadBalancer.addProcessor(Processor) Test.java   /first_camel/src/main/java/com/mycompany/first_camel    line 24 Java Problem
The type Test must implement the inherited abstract method LoadBalancer.getProcessors() Test.java   /first_camel/src/main/java/com/mycompany/first_camel    line 24 Java Problem
The type Test must implement the inherited abstract method LoadBalancer.removeProcessor(Processor)  Test.java   /first_camel/src/main/java/com/mycompany/first_camel    line 24 Java Problem
The type Test must implement the inherited abstract method Processor.process(Exchange)  Test.java   /first_camel/src/main/java/com/mycompany/first_camel    line 24 Java Problem
```

As i am new to both Java and Camel, i am finding it difficult to sort it out.

Any suggestion or help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

your class should implement RouteBuilder, not LoadBalancer...

see http://camel.apache.org/routes.html for details